# 404 error on getting kendo telerik source maps for `kendo.all.min.js`

Tags: asp.net-mvc, firefox, telerik, firefox-developer-tools

How can I get the source map working for `kendo.all.min.js` in my ASP.NET MVC 5 project running on IIS Express with Firefox 36 in Developer Tools?

In my html page (as seen by browser):

```
<script src="/Scripts/kendo/2014.3.1119/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
```

In `kendo.all.min.js`:

```
//# sourceMappingURL=kendo.all.min.js.map
```

Steps:

1. Open the page with FF with the Dev tools and enable 'Show original sources'. Result: the script is broken to many files shown in Sources pane on Debugger tab like: animation.js, attribution.js, kendo.grid.js, and many many more.
2. Click on `kendo.core.js` in the pane. Result: "HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found" error.

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried this yet: <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2014.3.1119/kendo.all.min.js")"></script> by the looks of it you are missing the tilde "~" before the /scripts so the page will look for a folder in your current route that is /script/..... for the kendo file

Comment: In .cshtml it is but in the sent html it is as stated above (from browser side). So that's not the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You need to write path correctly so you can write like this:

`<script src="~/Scripts/kendo/2014.3.1119/kendo.all.min.js"></script>`